# Read GPS data through UDP with Indy in Delphi

Tags: delphi, gps, indy, indy10, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a GPS device sending data to my IP through UDP.

This is how I read the UDP port:

```
procedure TForm3.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
  msg := BytesToString(AData);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('gps: '+msg);
end;
```

I get activity, but all I see is data like this:

```
gps: 
gps: 
gps:
```

**Update:**

I did some test with the `ipwUDPPort` component from [IP*Works](http://cdn.nsoftware.com/help/IP9/cs/UDPPort.htm).  Same behavior - all I see is a blank space:

```
procedure TFormUdpecho.UDPPort1DataIn(Sender: TObject; Datagram: String;
  const SourceAddress: String; SourcePort: Integer);
begin
    lTrack.Items.Add(SourceAddress + ':' + Datagram);
end;
```

I did another test with Indy:

```
procedure TForm3.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
  const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
begin
  msg :=  IntToStr( Length(AData) );
  Memo1.Lines.Add('gps: '+msg);
end;
```

And the result is this:

```
data: 126
data: 126
data: 127
data: 127
data: 127
```

Comment: Did you verify that `AData` is not empty? If `AData` is not empty, but `BytesToString()` returns a blank string, then there was a problem decoding the bytes to string characters. `BytesToString()` is charset-sensitive. Is the GPS data textual in nature to begin with, or is it binary? Try using `BytesToStringRaw()` instead. Also, do you have `IdUDPServer1.ThreadedEvent` set to True or False? If True, then it is not safe to access `Memo1` without syncing with the main UI thread (which is what `ThreadedEvent=False` does internally for you).

Comment: AData is not empty, IdUDPServer1.ThreadedEvent is false, I have and app that get the gps data and it get transmition, I'm just trying to make my own app, also I was testing ipwUDPPort1 from IP*works and It get the same behavior.

Comment: You didn't answer my question about the nature of `AData`'s content: "*Is the GPS data textual in nature to begin with, or is it binary?*"  What do the raw bytes actually look like? I'm guessing the data is actually binary, which would account for why you are having trouble converting it to a string. Also, what kind of GPS device exactly are you getting data from? Is there any documentation about the format of the UDP data it sends out?

Comment: the model of the GPS is enfora gsm2358, I think is the problem is convert the data, "What do the raw bytes actually look like?",How do I test this?

Comment: To see the byte values, you can use your debugger, or Delphi's [`Classes.BinToHex()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries//en/System.Classes.BinToHex) function, or Indy's `IdGlobal.ToHex()` function. In any case, the content of the UDP packets is indeed binary data, not text data. The format of the UDP packets is documented: [Enfora GSM/GPRS Family API Reference](http://documentation.nvtl.com/board/download/file.php?id=221).

Comment: ty for all ur help... but , what should I do now?, sorry for the noob question., can you guide me..

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please read the documentation I linked you to, and attempt to write your own code to process the UDP packets as needed. The doc tells you exactly how the UDP packets are laid out. I suggest you first log the hex values of the raw bytes so you can compare them to the doc. If the packets match the documented layout, then you will know the offsets of the GPS values within the packets, and Indy has many `BytesTo...()` functions for extracting integers, strings, etc from a `TIdBytes`. If you run into any troubles, post specific questions about that.

Comment: I get the hex data : "tohex(AData); " then use and hex to string online with this data and wuala , I can see the info of the gps, now Im trying to replicate the hex to string function on delphi but it getme a blank space... oh boy...

Comment: The hex string was just for display purposes to help you debug the UDP data at runtime.  DON'T process the UDP data as a hex string in your code!  You have the original bytes, process them as-is. Per the doc, the first 2 bytes comprise the "API number", the 3rd byte is the "command type", the 4th byte is the "API optional header length", then followed by the "optional header" if its length is not 0, followed by the command data, which is where the GPS data would be. Have you never worked with binary data before? If you can't figure this out, then please show the actual hex string.

Comment: "You have the original bytes, process them as-is. Per the doc, the first 2 bytes comprise the API number, the 3rd byte is the command type" , can you give a little tip that how to handle this data?

Comment: What is unclear about what I have already explained to you? You have an array of bytes (the `AData` parameter), and you have a PDF document (I gave you the link) that tells you what every byte means. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: "What is unclear about what I have already explained to you? You have an array of bytes (the AData parameter), and you have a PDF document (I gave you the link) that tells you what every byte means. What exactly are you having trouble with?"  Idk how to read that bytes, I dont understand pdf, you mean something like this?  "PAnsiChar(@AData[0]);",  what page of the pdf should I focus? ,  pd: im sorry

Comment: <sigh> Try something like this: `var ApiNum: Word; CmdType: Byte; OptHdr, CmdData: TIdBytes; ... ApiNum := BytesToUInt16(AData, 0); CmdType := AData[2]; OptHdr := ToBytes(AData, AData[3], 4); CmdData := ToBytes(AData, -1, 4+AData[3]); ... process OptHdr and CmdData based on CmdType as needed ...` Focus on Section 4.4 of the PDF.